# How Do I Debug Azure APIM Policies?

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an APIM policy using `choose` that is going down an unexpected logic path.

[How Do I Access Active Directory Users/Groups In An Azure APIM Policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698934/how-do-i-access-active-directory-users-groups-in-an-azure-apim-policy)

How do I debug this?

Is there a verbose mode that adds extra info to some logs?

Is it possible to dump the contents of the `context` or `context.User` or `context.User.Groups` to a log file that I can read?

How would I do that and where would the log file be?

Answer (score 5):

Currently you cannot really debug.

You may add `<trace source="yourtraceidentifier">@(...your expression to trace goes here...)</trace>` policy expressions which you would see

1. in the developer portal trace
2. on the URL emitted by the response HTTP header **Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location: https://apimstoxnurcnsqhqwudvs35.blob.core.windows.net/apiinspectorcont...** when you turn on the HTTP header **Ocp-Apim-Trace: true**
3. in the future this trace information should also be emitted to Application Insights telemetry as trace elements

**correction August 2021**

With the [Visual Studio extension for API Management](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-apimanagement) it is possible to debug policies : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-debug-policies